# How can I make a geographic map with data in specific regions at multiple levels?

Tags: javascript, maps, geospatial, geography

I have some data I would like to represent at the US state and city level.

So I would like the map to start out showing the US, with a number associated with each state.

When a user clicks on a state, the map will zoom into that state and show numbers associated with each city.

I was surprised to find that there don't seem to be any mapping libraries which support this sort of thing. I would have to integrate the boundary data and write the behavior myself. It seems like this would be a pretty common problem to solve, so maybe I am searching with the wrong keywords. (On that note, please feel free to recommend different tags or title for this question)

Comment: What sort of data is this you're trying to represent?

Comment: Have a look at jvectormap.com , it is a library (need jquery) which can display svg as map. The API exposes events as you requested.

Comment: @Alex it's a number associated with each region

Comment: @MickdK thanks, I will take a look